# FFMPEG Windows Generate 360p Video conversion failed

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video-conversion

Input :

```
"C:/server/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe" -y -i C:\server\websites\ps\public_www/media/com_hwdmediashare/files/50/4f/37/4185216cb9bb234fd47ee43bf2122e4f.avi -strict experimental -acodec aac -ac 2 -ab 192k -s 480x360 -aspect 16:9 -r 24000/1001 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 1000k -minrate 800k -maxrate 1000k -bufsize 800K -crf 18 -preset veryslow -f mp4 -threads 0 -movflags +faststart C:\server\websites\ps\public_www/media/com_hwdmediashare/files/50/4f/37/de8324ea7b8fe7a28ccc701f0ae757c8.mp4 2>&1
```

Output :

```
    ffmpeg version N-65916-g9e8ab36 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 26 2014 22:10:59 with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
  libavcodec     56.  0.101 / 56.  0.101
  libavformat    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavfilter     5.  0.103 /  5.  0.103
  libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
[avi @ 0000000002c5c2c0] non-interleaved AVI
[mp3 @ 0000000002b2b220] Header missing
Input #0, avi, from 'C:\server\websites\ps\public_www/media/com_hwdmediashare/files/50/4f/37/4185216cb9bb234fd47ee43bf2122e4f.avi':
  Duration: 00:06:46.47, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1144 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (DX50 / 0x30355844), yuv420p, 512x384 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1106 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 30k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 11025 Hz, stereo, s16p, 31 kb/s
[libx264 @ 0000000002b87da0] using SAR=4/3
[libx264 @ 0000000002b87da0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0000000002b87da0] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0000000002b87da0] 264 - core 142 r2453 ea0ca51 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=16 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x133 me=umh subme=10 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=24 chroma_me=1 trellis=2 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=8 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=2 b_bias=0 direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=23 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=60 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=18.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=1000 vbv_bufsize=800 crf_max=0.0 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[aac @ 0000000002b88de0] Too many bits per frame requested
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\server\websites\ps\public_www/media/com_hwdmediashare/files/50/4f/37/de8324ea7b8fe7a28ccc701f0ae757c8.mp4':
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 480x360 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 1000 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.0.101 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 0 channels, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.0.101 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp3 (native) -> aac (native))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

I cant see what has gone wrong with the conversion perhaps someone can assist me ?

Comment: You're using two mutually exclusive methods for rate control, `-b:v`, and `-crf`. In this case `-b:v` is likely to be ignored since `-crf` was listed after it. Also, you probably should not add `-minrate`, but I'm not sure exactly what your use case is for the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error from the native FFmpeg AAC encoder (`-acodec aac -strict experimental`) when attempting to force too high of a bitrate for the given audio rate.

I can think of seven methods to resolve this issue:

- decrease your audio bitrate, such as `-ab 64k` (you may have to experiment), or
- use `-aq 10` for VBR audio instead of `-ab`, or
- increase your audio rate, such as `-ar 44100`, or
- use a different AAC audio encoder, such as `-acodec libvoaac_enc`, or
- pipe from `ffmpeg` to an external, standalone AAC encoder, then remux with `ffmpeg`, or
- [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux) the audio using `-acodec copy`, or
- output to a different audio format, such as MP3 by using `-acodec libmp3lame`

Unfortunately, distributed builds of `ffmpeg` often only provide the native AAC encoder and libvoaac_enc, but there are better AAC encoders supported by FFmpeg, such as libfdk_aac, but you would have to [compile `ffmpeg`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide) to gain support for this.

See the [FFmpeg AAC Audio Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) for more details.

Comment: Thanks LordNeckbeard will that cause problems with other video conversions or can i use the same for others too and they will not give of a error.

Comment: Also i came accross the following : Please note that wmav1,wmav2 and libvo_aacenc don't seem to be able to reach transparency at any given bitrate. It seems ffmpeg do not recommend for me to use that encoder. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/HighQualityAudio I will also mention you said several methods to resolve the problem but you posted 3 what are the other 4 ?

Comment: You can probably use the same options and values for most of your other videos. The info in the link you provided may be highly subjective (and written by users, not developers) but it is generally agreed upon that libvo_aacenc is not a great AAC encoder, but you don't have much choice with your build.

Comment: Did anyone ever come up with reasonable `-qscale` values for `aac`?

Comment: Thanks for the info the problem with switching to -acodec libmp3lame is for all IOS (Apple device users) when you watch MP4 videos with a mp3 codec they cant hear any audio i have added -ar 44100 and decrease my audio bit rate to -ar 128k and will let you know if the result is the same.

Comment: @slhck The [AAC guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) mentions 0.1 to 10. I'm not sure how up-to-date or accurate that is, but I believe it was added by [Kamedo2](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/kamedo2/) who probably knows more about it than anyone else. I've never performed any listening tests.